# Check if my trajectory colliding another objects

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to Math.stackechange and i'm a programmer not a mathematician :-(.

I'm solving problem in 3D engine for a computer game.
But this time i need to do calculations on server side, matemathically, I can't use a OpenGL.

I have trajectory of a ship from A to B in a Space.

```
A=Vector3(x,y,z) 
B=Vector3(x,y,z)
```

I need to calculate, if my trajectory is colliding with some planets.
For each planet i have its Position (`Vector3(x,y,z)`) and a `Radius`.

My humble try to make solution:

```
B-A = C //(trajectory vector)
i = C/length_of_C
```

and loop `i`-times:

`C*i+A` // and test if it is close to any planet

But distances are so huge (bilions of Km) and planets are too small (thousands of km). That on trajectory Earth <> Pluto i need to repeat this loop a milion times. That is not possible.

It is possible to calculate for each planet distance to nearest point of trajectory A=>B ?

Comment: Are the planets in motion while the ship is moving? If so, then the problem will be much harder.

Comment: @Semiclassical no, Space is completely static.

Comment: it is distance berween planet Vector3(x,y,z) position (center) in all direction. Radius of planetary sphere, or a planetary circle in 2D. If is distance of nearest point of trajectory smaller than radius, then I need to detect hit.

Comment: So the ship doesn't stop at $B$? Its trajectory is the ray which starts at $A$, goes through $B$ and then on forever, correct?

Comment: No, Only from A to B. Mean of spaceship flying from A to B, i need to know if that trajectory is free, or blocked by some planet.

Answer (score 2):

This is the three-dimensional version of [Shortest distance between two objects moving along two lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775476/shortest-distance-between-two-objects-moving-along-two-lines) with one of the velocities set to zero.
If the spaceship travels in a straight line from
$A(x_A,y_A,z_A)$ to $B(x_B,y_B,z_B)$ and
your planet is at the coordinates $P(x_P,y_P,z_P)$,
define the vector $V(x_V,y_V,z_V) = B - A$ 
and the vector $U(x_U,y_U,z_U) = P - A$.

In vector arithmetic, what we do is to project $U$ onto $V$,
obtaining a vector $U_V$, and then
subtract $U_V$ from $U$, which leaves a vector $U_\perp$
perpendicular to $V$.
Then $U_\perp$ is the vector to $P$ from $A + U_V$,
which the closest point to $P$ along the line of $V$.
It's also convenient to define an auxiliary variable $t_{\min}$
so that the calculations go as follows:
\begin{align}
t_{\min} &= \frac{U \cdot V}{\lVert V \rVert^2},\\
U_V &= t_{\min} V, \\
U_\perp &= U - U_V.
\end{align}
If $A + U_V$ is between $A$ and $B$ then $\lVert U_\perp\rVert$
is the distance of closest approach to $P$ on the path from $A$ to $B$.
That occurs when $0 < t_{\min} < 1$.
In that case you want to compare $\lVert U_\perp\rVert$
to the radius of the planet to see if you "hit" it.
If $t_{\min} \leq 0$ then $A$ is the closest
point to $P$ and if $t_{\min} \geq 1$
then $B$ is the closest point to $P$ along the path from $A$ to $B$.

In practice, it is usually faster to compute $\lVert U_\perp\rVert^2$
than to compute $\lVert U_\perp\rVert$,
so if the planet's radius is $r$, you might try testing whether
$\lVert U_\perp\rVert^2 \leq r^2$
to see if you "hit".

Depending on your vector arithmetic library, if a "dot product" function
is defined then that is probably how you would get $U \cdot V$.
Then $\lVert V \rVert^2 = V \cdot V$
and $\Vert U_\perp \rVert = \sqrt{U_\perp \cdot U_\perp}$.
The implementation of the "dot product" function should be something
equivalent to $U \cdot V = x_U x_V + y_U y_V + z_U z_V$
in case you need to implement it yourself.

---

By the way, if the planet *is* moving, but both the spaceship and planet
are moving along straight lines at constant speed,
you can subtract the planet's velocity vector from the spaceship's
velocity vector to get the vector $V$, and proceed as before.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Sorry for slightly changing the notation in your question. In this answer, $\vec C$ is the position of the planet.

The line which goes through $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ can be parameterized as $$\vec{l}(t) = t(\vec{B}-\vec{A}) + \vec{A}$$ Here $t$ is any real number and $\vec{l}(t)$ is any point on the line. Assuming the ship starts at $\vec{A}$ and ends at $\vec{B}$, the trajectory should be taken only for $0\leq t \leq 1$.

The point on this line which is closest to $\vec{C}$ will be the point $\vec{l}(t)$ where the vector from $\vec{l}(t)$ to $\vec{C}$ is perpendicular to the line, i.e. perpendicular to $\vec B - \vec A$. In other words, we need to solve the equation $$(\vec C - \vec l(t)) \cdot (\vec B - \vec A) = 0$$ which can be rewritten as $$\vec C\cdot (\vec B-\vec A) - t|\vec B - \vec A|^2 - \vec A \cdot (\vec B-\vec A) = 0$$ $$t = \frac{(\vec C-\vec A)\cdot (\vec B-\vec A)}{|\vec B - \vec A|^2}$$ If $0\leq t\leq 1$, then this is actually a point on the ship's trajectory. In that case, the closest distance between the trajectory and the planet is $|\vec C - \vec l(t)|$ for the above value of $t$. If $t < 0$, then the closest point on the trajectory to the planet is actually $\vec A$ itself (the ship is flying away from the planet), so this distance is $|\vec C - \vec A|$. If $t > 1$, then $\vec B$ is the closest point and the distance is $|\vec C - \vec B|$ (the ship stops before getting closer to the planet).