# Calculate the smallest distance between the objects

Tags: plane-curves, plane-geometry

I tried solving below problem. But didn't got the complete solution. Please help. Any help will be appreciated

Two particles, 1 and 2, move with constant velocities v1 and v2 along two mutually perpendicular straight lines toward the intersection point O. At the moment t = 0 the particles were located at the distances l1 and l2 from the point 0. How soon will the distance between the particles become the smallest? What is it equal to?

Comment: This may not be an exact duplicate, but it is extremely close to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775476 -- the main difference is how you describe the problem. The fact that your two lines are perpendicular is a minor simplification in some methods of solving this, but irrelevant in my preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strategy for you:

1: calculate the trajectories of both points as linear functions: $y = mx + n$ (you will need to make a special case for a purely vertical line)

2: calculate the intersection point of these linear functions $y_1 = y_2 \Leftrightarrow m_1x + n_1 = m_2x + n2$

3:  calculate the time needed for each point to reach that intersection

4: it the time durations are equal, the points collide, otherwise they don't

Comment: If you use the normal form of the equation of a line $ax+by+c=0$, there’s no need to handle vertical lines separately.